# How to use Google Docs Viewer with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, google-document-viewer

I want to preview documents by Google Docs Viewer via puppeteer that runs in Node.js.
The URL works well in browser: 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.npmjs.com%2Fimages%2Fnpm.svg&embedded=true

But throws error in puppeteer:

```
(async () => {          
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();           
        page.on('response', res => {
            res.text().then(text => {
                console.log('response:', {
                    url: res.url(),
                    status: res.status(),
                    res_headers: res.headers(),
                    req_headers: res.request().headers(),
                    text: text
                });
            });
        });

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
        let content = await page.content();            
        await browser.close();

        return content;
    })();
```

Printed events:

**url**: [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.f5JujS1eFMY.O/m=googleapis_proxy/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNDI1_ftdVIpg6jNiygedEKTreQ2A/cb=gapi.loaded_0](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.f5JujS1eFMY.O/m=googleapis_proxy/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNDI1_ftdVIpg6jNiygedEKTreQ2A/cb=gapi.loaded_0)

**status**: 200

**console**: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

**url**: https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2internal/about?fields=importFormats,kind&key=AIzaSyDVQw45DwoYh632gvsP5vPDqEKvb-Ywnb8

**text**: {"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "global", "reason": "required","message": "Login Required","locationType": "header","location": "Authorization"}],"code": 401,"message": "Login Required"}}

**url**: 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2internal/viewerimpressions?key=AIzaSyDVQw45DwoYh632gvsP5vPDqEKvb-Ywnb8&alt=json'

**status**: 204

**console**: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()'

**url**: 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2internal/apps?fields=items(authorized,chromeExtensionIds,createInFolderTemplate,createUrl,icons(iconUrl,size,category),id,installed,kind,longDescription,name,objectType,openUrlTemplate,origins,primaryFileExtensions,primaryMimeTypes,productId,productUrl,rankingInfo,removable,requiresAuthorizationBeforeOpenWith,secondaryFileExtensions,secondaryMimeTypes,shortDescription,supportsCreate,supportsImport,supportsMultiOpen,supportsTeamDrives,type,useByDefault),kind&languageCode=en-US&key=AIzaSyDVQw45DwoYh632gvsP5vPDqEKvb-Ywnb8',

**text**: {"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "global","reason": "forbidden","message": "Forbidden"}],"code": 403,"message": "Forbidden"}},

When I compare cookies and headers between puppeter and the browser, the headers "origin", "x-origin", "x-referrer" are the same, but the "x-chrome-connected" and "x-client-date" are missing.

The cookie "NID" exists.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at Google's responses:

> {"errors": [{"domain": "global", "reason": "required","message": "**Login Required**"}]}
>
> {"errors": [{"domain": "global","reason": "forbidden","message": "**Forbidden**"}]}

It seems that puppeteer Chromium needs to be logged in with Google to use the PDF viewer feature.

Comment: That's the question. How to overcome these errors? If I just put the upper link in browser with anonymous session everything works correct without any logins.

Comment: That's a good question and I suppose it's not a technical one, but has something to do with Google's permissions and quotas.

Comment: But how google can distinguish between puppeter and browser? The agents and origins are the same.

Comment: A couple months ago I wanted to use this viewer in an iframe on a client's site and also got denied so I though it could be some permissions issue?